# Codeblocks toolbars stop responding

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, code-blocks

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a virtual machine (virtual box)

I installed code blocks and i started coding but sometimes, the visual interface is bugging and some toolbars don't show up.

Example: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vzv7F.png)

In this example, it's the file selection toolbar that doesn't work. It is there, but not refreshing.

Sometimes, it's the button toolbar (run, run&build, build, etc) that doesn't work, but sometimes it's the project arborescence tree on the left that disappear. And sometimes, all of them at the same time.

I'll add that this is not a problem of disactivated toolbars, they just disappear as if they crashed and stopped working. Usually, the toolbars are here but when i do some certain kind of actions (open a context menu for example) then some toolbars stop responding.

I don't know if it's a Codeblocks problem, or linux, or the virtual machine software, but it's quite annoying to program with half the interface missing :(

If you have any ideas or questions, please tell/ask me ;)

Thanks by advance
See ya!

Answer (score 0):

The apt-get install codeblocks command doesn't install the latest version of codeblocks.

I installed using the PPA from the website and it worked